# Retrieve most frequent values from each column within groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For each group, grouped using field GRP, I would like to retrieve the most frequently occurring value in column A and the most frequently occurring value in column B, and potentially do this for many other columns.

Sample Data:

```
GRP | A | B
-----------
Cat | 1 | 1
Cat | 2 | 1
Cat | 3 | 2
Cat | 3 | 3
Dog | 5 | 6
Dog | 5 | 7
Dog | 6 | 7
```

Expected Output:

```
GRP | A | B
-----------
Cat | 3 | 1
Dog | 5 | 7
```

This query achieves that result:

```
SELECT 
    freq1.GRP,
    freq1.A,
    freq2.B
FROM (
        SELECT
            GRP,
            A,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS F_RANK
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY GRP, A
) AS freq1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            GRP,
            B,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS F_RANK
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY GRP, B
) AS freq2 ON freq2.GRP = freq1.GRP
WHERE freq1.F_RANK = 1 AND freq2.F_RANK = 1
```

It just doesn't look very efficient, and even less so if I were to add a column C, D, etc...

Is there a better way?

Comment: sample data and expected output would help clarify your question.

Comment: Added sample data and output per your suggestion

Comment: What is the expected output if 2 values are jointly most frequently occurring?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Good question. In the scenario I am using this query for it doesn't matter and I just need one of the most frequently occurring values.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say this approach is "better" because it will generate the exact same execution plan. However, I find this type of approach a lot more maintainable as the number of columns might grow. For me this is a lot easier to read.

```
with GroupA as
(
    select Grp
        , A
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by grp order by count(*) desc) as RowNum
    from MyTable
    group by Grp, A
)
, GroupB as
(
    select Grp
        , B
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by grp order by count(*) desc) as RowNum
    from MyTable
    group by Grp, B
)

select a.Grp
    , a.A
    , b.B
from GroupA a
inner join GroupB b on a.Grp = b.Grp and b.RowNum = 1
where a.RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using results ranked in a temp table:

```
SELECT  GRP, A, B,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY GRP, A) ARank, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY GRP, B) BRank
INTO #TMP
FROM MyTable

SELECT t1.GRP, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 A FROM #TMP WHERE GRP = t1.Grp ORDER BY ARank DESC) A, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 B FROM #TMP WHERE GRP = t1.Grp ORDER BY BRank DESC) B 
FROM MyTable t1
GROUP BY T1.GRP 

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

### [Full Solution on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6407/1)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    ([GRP] varchar(3), [A] int, [B] int)
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    ([GRP], [A], [B])
VALUES
    ('Cat', 1, 1),
    ('Cat', 2, 1),
    ('Cat', 3, 2),
    ('Cat', 3, 3),
    ('Dog', 5, 6),
    ('Dog', 5, 7),
    ('Dog', 6, 7)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  GRP, A, B,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY GRP, A) ARank, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY GRP, B) BRank
INTO #TMP
FROM MyTable

SELECT t1.GRP, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 A FROM #TMP WHERE GRP = t1.Grp ORDER BY ARank DESC) A, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 B FROM #TMP WHERE GRP = t1.Grp ORDER BY BRank DESC) B 
FROM MyTable t1
GROUP BY T1.GRP 

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6407/1/0)**:

```
| GRP | A | B |
|-----|---|---|
| Cat | 3 | 1 |
| Dog | 5 | 7 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start out this answer by saying this is **NOT** going to be more efficient to run - it should just be easier to add/subtract columns.  To do this you just add them into the code in two places.

You can use dynamic SQL to build your result set like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##fields (id INT IDENTITY(1,1),fieldname VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO ##fields
        ( fieldname )
VALUES  ('A'),('B') --Add field names here
DECLARE @maxid INT
SELECT @maxid = MAX(id) FROM ##fields

CREATE TABLE ##Output (GRP VARCHAR(3), A INT, B INT) --Add field names here

INSERT INTO ##Output
        ( GRP )
SELECT DISTINCT GRP FROM MyTable

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT = 1

WHILE @i <=@maxid
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = 'with cte as (SELECT  GRP , ' + fieldname + ' ,
                                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS F_RANK
                                    FROM    MyTable
                                    GROUP BY GRP , ' + fieldname + ')
                        UPDATE O
                        SET O.' + fieldname + ' = cte.' + fieldname + '
                        FROM ##Output O
                        INNER JOIN cte ON O.GRP = cte.GRP AND cte.F_Rank = 1' FROM ##fields WHERE id = @i
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END


SELECT *
FROM ##Output

DROP TABLE ##fields
DROP TABLE ##Output
```

Using your simple example above, I received the following performance stats:

**Dynamic SQL**
CPU = 31
Reads = 504
Duration = 39

**Your SQL**
CPU = 0
Reads = 6
Duration = 1

Clearly, this way is not a more efficient way of doing this.  I did want to throw it out there anyway as an alternative to your current method.

Answer (score 0):

First we create the test data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    GRP varchar(10),
    A int,
    B int
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( GRP, A, B)
VALUES
('Cat', 1, 1),
('Cat', 2, 1),
('Cat', 3, 2),
('Cat', 3, 3),
('Dog', 5, 6),
('Dog', 5, 7),
('Dog', 6, 7);
```

Now we use first_value from a subselect (or a cte if you wanted) and grab the top cat and dog columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    GRP,
    FIRST_VALUE(A) OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY d.A_CNT DESC) AS A_RANK,
    FIRST_VALUE(B) OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY d.B_CNT DESC) AS B_RANK
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        GRP, 
        A, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY GRP, A) AS A_CNT,
        B, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY GRP, B) AS B_CNT
    FROM @MyTable
) d
```

Output:

```
GRP A_RANK  B_RANK
Cat 3   1
Dog 5   7
```